# How to make icon background transparent in PyQt>?

Tags: python, pyqt, icons

I use a menu icon with white background. When I start my program I see this white background on gray menu item. It does not look nice. How to make white background transparent for not to see white color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a transparent image to begin with, where everything except the menu are empty pixels( `png` format).

Your pyqt application can't differentiate between what's background and foreground.

You can try and remove the image background online [here](https://clippingmagic.com)

Answer (score 2):

Try these approaches:

1. self.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;)
2. self.setFlags(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
3. You have also the option of setting up a mask

---

```
def make_transparent(self):

    self.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")

    mMask = QPixmap(self.width(), self.height())
    mMask.fill(Qt.transparent)

    p = QPainter()
    p.begin(mMask)
    p.setPen(Qt.red)
    p.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))

    p.drawRect(QRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000))

    p.end()

    self.setMask(mMask.mask())
```

**Just adapt to size and color you want.**

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand completely. I load icon by QIcon into QAction and then add to menu. What should I apply setStyleSheet for, etc.?

Comment: In summary we have: 1-the stylesheet can be applied in anything that is a type of Widget with a CSS syntax, so you can personalize that. 2- A flag that is applied to a Object as some kind of property that you can override the default one, just have a look in the API. 3- The last case for example is creating a pixmap from nothing setting its size and making it transparent, it means you are creating your own transparent pixmap, after that it'd be applied to the QObject you are working with as a mask making it transparent and the rest of the things in it would keep solid color.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I was trying to remove background of my pixmap. Thank you my friend from the past

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't help with the current question but it's for the people who will come in the future looking for a way to set a transparent Icon.

So I wanted to get rid of the default windows Icon and I didn't have any logo for the application either so I thought that making the Icon transparent would get rid of that windows icon.

```py
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(255, 255)
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,0))
    MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(pixmap))
```